# How to set JVM parameters in CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I want to set CMSClassUnloadingEnabled and UseConcMarkSweepGC for my Ruby on Rails application running on CloudBees.  I'm struggling to find the syntax for setting these using the bees SDK or can I set them in warble.rb?

thanks!

-max

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set options via the CLI/SDK, for example:

```
bees app:deploy app.war -R JAVA_OPTS="-verbose:class"
```

The -R JAVA_OPTS will pass along the parameters you want.